# Do alerts expire?

Tags: 2010, alert

I and a couple others set up alerts on a site (two different site collections were involved), but they disappeared. (It's a little confusing to talk about all three of our experiences at once, so I'm going to share mine - the other two experienced basically the same.)

I had an alert set up on two lists in my site and was receiving weekly notifications. One week, they stopped. I checked the "My alerts" page, and they had disappeared. I definitely didn't delete them, and I'm the SME (subject matter expert) on our team, so no one would go in and delete them without asking me first.

My question: do alerts expire after a certain amount of time? If not, I'm guessing it was a glitch that our SP admins caused, but they didn't realize it.

Comment: What is the list type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any conditions that could cause an alert to "expire" or otherwise be automatically pruned. Even when a document on which alerts are set expires or is deleted, the alerts will remain (which is honestly kind of an annoyance). If I had to venture a guess, it's either database corruption or some type of accident.

Someone with site owner privileges can view the alerts of all users on their site, and even delete them, and it's possible they deleted yours by mistake. I can envision this happening somewhat easily in one case, because in that view you select the user whose alerts you want to see with a drop-down menu, and if you delete *all* of their alerts, it shows the alerts for the next user in the list but *doesn't change the name in the drop-down menu* which could lead to the user believing they didn't actually delete the correct alerts and trying again, deleting the next user's alerts and so on.

**Edit:** I should add that I've seen that behavior in 2010, I don't know if it's consistent across other versions, but since you tagged the question with 2010 I believe it's a likely explanation.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured happened - thank you!